# Getting error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1" when trying to select second option from the drop down list

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select the third option from the drop down list. Drop down list is written in the `div` tag. I am only getting the size of drop down list as 1 but there are total 10 items in the drop down. Below is the Selenium code :

```java
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Clicking the drop down list
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='selectedItem']"));
element.click();

// Here I am trying to fetch all options in the drop down list.
List<WebElement> options= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdownItems open']"));  
int size = options.size();

//There are 10 items in the drop down list but I am getting only one as a result.
System.out.println(size);

//Here I am getting the error for "Out of Bound"
options.get(1).click();

Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Since you are missing information it is hard to tell - you forgot to post your HTML. My guess: change `By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdownItems open']")` to `By.classname("dropdownItems")`. Keep in mind that the `class` attribute in HTML is a **space separated list** of classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think that here

```java
List<WebElement> options= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdownItems open']"));
```

you just get the same element as here

```java
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='selectedItem']"));
```

but which changed its class after you have clicked it. So you're getting list of 1 item.

The thing is that the options are the elements **inside** that list. Check your html. For example if there is something like this:

```html
<div class='dropdownItems open'>
  <div>Option 1</div>
  <div>Option 1</div>
  <div>Option 1</div>
</div>
```

then you would need to use the following code:

```java
List<WebElement> options= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdownItems open']/div"));
```

i.e. extend your xpath with which items inside your list you would like to query.